How to implement a virtualized tree structure using tanstack/virtual
I'm implementing a pivot table. I want to use react-virtual to implement the virtualization of the pivot row/column headers. May I know how to achieve that? I wonder if I should use nested virtualization, or flatten the different rows in column headers and virtualize them separately.
Should I use tanstack-table if this is supported there already?

